# Matlab's convmtx2 equivalent in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

Matlab has this very handy convmtx2 function, that allows to write a 2D convolution as a matrix multiplication (between a convolution matrix computed from the convolution kernel and the image, flattened as a 1d vector). Is there anything similar as a Python implementation available?

Comment: For now, I solved my problem using `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator` to implicitly compute the product, however the question still remains relevant for me.